# Giving a counterexample to $ 2^{n-1}- 1 = n \cdot a \iff n \text{ is prime}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples

Fermat's little theorem asserts: $ n \text{ is prime} \implies 2^{n-1}- 1 = n \cdot a $.

However , the converse ,  $ 2^{n-1}- 1 = n \cdot a  \implies  n$ is prime, is not true . How can we prove it , **taking odd $n$** (without using a computer)?

Edit:
I know that $341$ works , but how can I prove it's a counterexample without using a computer?

Comment: $2^{4-1} = 8 = 4\times 2$

Comment: $n=4$ implies that $2^3=4\times a$. Thus, $a=2$, and $n=4$ is not prime.

Comment: Generally speaking, to disprove something, all you need to do is find one counterexample. In this case, all that that requires is picking an $n$ that doesn't work.

Comment: These counterexamples are called Fermat pseudoprimes base 2.  [The smallest example is $n=11\cdot 31=341$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime#:~:text=The%20smallest%20base%2D2%20Fermat,test%20for%20the%20base%202.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [hardmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3111/hardmath), you are looking for pseudoprimes base $2$, and $341$ is a counterexample.  To prove it without using a computer, note that $2^{5}=32=31+1\equiv1\bmod31$ and $2^5=32=33-1\equiv-1\bmod11$, so $2^{10}\equiv1\bmod31$ and $11$ and therefore $\bmod 341$, so $2^{340}\equiv1\bmod341$.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number). The smallest Carmichael number is $n=561=3\cdot 11\cdot 17$ and it satisfies $$b^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$ for all $b$ such that $b$ is relatively prime to $561.$

Answer (score 1):

Simple: prove that $2^{340} \equiv1 \pmod{341}$

We have $341=11\cdot31 \implies \phi(341) =300$
and by euler's theorem,
$$2^{300} \equiv1 \pmod{341}$$
Now, $2^{40} \equiv 1024^4 \equiv1^4 \equiv1\pmod{341}$
and multiplying the two congruences we get the required result